# Последний элемент многомерного массива через length - 1

Tags: javascript, массивы

Изучаю JS, поэтому надеюсь вопрос не слишком глупый. Хотел добраться до последнего элемента многомерного массива через length - 1, но не понял как обратиться к этому элементу.

```
let massive = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, [7, 'this']]];
```

Пытался так, но естественно это неверный вариант:

```
console.log(massive[massive.length - 1][massive.length - 1][massive.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Многомерных массивов не существует. То, что вы называете многомерным массивом, на самом деле является массивом массивов. Т.е. массивом, у которого элементы являются массивами

```js
let massive = [
  [1, 2, 3],  // 0 элемент
  [3, 4, 5],  // 1 элемент
  [6, [7, 'this']]  // 2 элемент
];
```

Таким образом конструкция `massive[massive.length - 1]` вам вернет элемент-массив `[6, [7, 'this']]` со своей длиной равной два. И т.д.

Чтобы получить "последний" скалярный элемент вам нужно последовательно перебрать все вложенные массивы и взять из полученного массива последний элемент. Проще всего это сделать рекурсией.

```js
let massive = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, [7, 'this']]];

function getLast(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr))
    return getLast(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  else
    return arr;
}

console.log(getLast(massive));
```

Comment: Теперь все понятно, спасибо!

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под словом <скалярный>?

Comment: @Demon__ В данном случае - не массив.